# error 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key'

Tags: c#, oracle

error 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key'
my connection string is ok. I am sure
I use another connection string and get the same error

```
//string connecstion="Data Source=his1:1521/HIST;UserId=net;Password=netnet";

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        

        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = his1)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = HIST))); User Id = net; Password = netnet;");

        //when want open connection get error 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key'
        conn.Open();

        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();


    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I has the same error code and it was related to an outdated Oracle.ManagementDataAccess. By setting target .net framework to 4.7.2 and update Oracle.ManagementDataAccess to 2021 update I solved the problem.